# Count number of occurences of each string using regex

Tags: python-3.x, regex, python-re

Given a pattern like this

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\b(A|B|C)\b')
```

And a `huge_string` I would like to replace every substring matching the pattern with a string `D` and find the number of occurences for each string `A`, `B` and `C`. What is the most feasible approach?

One way is to split the pattern to 3 patterns for each string and then use subn

```
pattern_a = re.compile(r'\bA\b')
pattern_b = re.compile(r'\bB\b')
pattern_c = re.compile(r'\bC\b')
huge_string, no_a = re.subn(pattern_a, D, huge_string)
huge_string, no_b = re.subn(pattern_b, D, huge_string)
huge_string, no_c = re.subn(pattern_c, D, huge_string)
```

But it requires 3 passes through the huge_string. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may pass a callable as the replacement argument to `re.sub` and collect the necessary counting details during a single replacement pass:

```
import re

counter = {}

def repl(m):
    if m.group() in counter:
        counter[m.group()] += 1
    else:
        counter[m.group()] = 1
    return 'd'

text = "a;b o a;c a l l e d;a;c a b"
rx = re.compile(r'\b(a|b|c)\b')
result = rx.sub(repl, text)
print(counter, result, sep="\n")
```

See the [Python demo online](https://ideone.com/FEc2rE), output;

```
{'a': 5, 'b': 2, 'c': 2}
d;d o d;d d l l e d;d;d d d
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do it in 2 passes, the first just counting then the second doing the sub. this will mean if your search space grows like a|b|c|d|e etc you will still only do 2 passes, your number of passes will not be based on your number of possible matches.

```py
import re
from collections import Counter

string = " a j h s j a b c "
pattern = re.compile(r'\b(a|b|c)\b')
counts = Counter(pattern.findall(string))
string_update = pattern.sub('d', string)
print(counts, string, string_update, sep="\n")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Counter({'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'c': 1})
 a j h s j a b c 
 d j h s j d d d
```